# catching `KeyError` and replacing with MSG

Tags: python, json, dictionary

am querying a `JSON` dict where there's some keys is not available.

my aim is to type `N/A` for the key which `KeyError` occurs in then write to file.

```
goal = ['name', 'age', 'gender']


for item in r['data']:
    final = [item[x] for x in goal]
    writer.writerow(final)
```

I know that can be done via `Try/Except` but i don't know how to handle it correctly

```
try:
    final = [item[x] for x in goal]
except KeyError as e:
    # from here am struggling
```

Example:

```
g = [
    {'name': 'ahmed', 'age': '10', 'gender': 'M'},
    {'name': 'mohamed', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'ramy'}
]
```

Desired output:

```
['ahmed', '10', 'M']
['moahmed','20','N/A']
['ramy','N/A','N/A']
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of the json and your expected output?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Javascript, Python throws an exception when there is no key in a dictionary.
So you have to check if there is a key.

```py
final = [item[x] for x in goal]
```

Change this code in to this

```py
final = [(item[x] if x in item else 'N/A') for x in goal]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try another way with `dict.get` and a list comprehension:

```
g = [
    {'name': 'ahmed', 'age': '10', 'gender': 'M'},
    {'name': 'mohamed', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'ramy'}
]

goal = ['name', 'age', 'gender']

print([[d.get(k, "N/A") for k in goal] for d in g]) # when python couldn't find the key, return "N/A"
# [['ahmed', '10', 'M'], ['mohamed', '20', 'N/A'], ['ramy', 'N/A', 'N/A']]
```

Comment: Thank you. `.get` is actually new for me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `try`/`except`, I would check if the key exists (with `key in dic` or `dic.has_key(key)`).

```
final = []
for x in goal:
    if x in item:
        final.append(item[x])
     else:
        final.append('N/A')
```

Can be shortened with `dic.get` and list comprehension:

```
final = [item.get(x, 'N/A') for x in goal]
```

Using `try`/`except`:

```
final = []
for x in goal:
    try:
        vaule = item[x]
     except KeyError as e:
        value = 'N/A'
     final.append(value)
```